# Проверка строк на наличие в них цифр

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как проверить строку, которую я ввожу на наличие в ней цифр?

Answer (score 11):

```
any(map(str.isdigit, 'qwe1'))  # bool
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [123]: import re

In [126]: re.search('\d+', 'aaaa 123 bbb') is not None
Out[126]: True

In [127]: re.search('\d+', 'aaaa bbb ccc') is not None
Out[127]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
print('Int%s exist in string' % ('' if any(map(str.isdigit, input('Input str:'))) else ' not'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверка вхождения символа или группы символов в строку:

```
x = str(12345)
text = ".......12345......"
>>> x in text
True
```

Если нужно узнать есть ли указанные цифры:

```
if [s for s in text if s in '12345']: print 'True'
```

условие сработает если в `text` будет содержаться хотя бы одна цифра из указанных `'12345'`